# Android Studio adding jar Error

Tags: android, android-studio

```
 Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'MYPROJECT'.
```

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            file:/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4/httpcore-4.4.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4/httpcore-4.4.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4/httpcore-4.4.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4/httpcore-4.4.jar
>        Required by:
>            :MYPROJECT

I am getting the above error when adding a jar file

what i did:

CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+S .... went to Dependencies...plus button..searched for httpcore and added it.
when running the project, the above error came.

i went to the location where C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository
and all what is in this file is a folder com and 2 files

also i found out that the jar files i am looking for are found in: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib.

so please if anyone can guide me and tell me what the problem is.

i also tried after that adding the jar files to the libs folder but then got this error:

```
 Execution failed for task ':packageDebug'.
```

> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
>       File 1: D:\AndroidStudioProjects\project\libs\httpmime-4.3.4.jar
>       File 2: D:\AndroidStudioProjects\project\libs\httpmime-4.3.4.jar

build.gradle:

```
 apply plugin: 'android'

 dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

 }

 buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+'
   }
 }
android {
compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
 }
```

NOTE: i imported this project from eclipse and it used to work fine.

Comment: Do you have `mavenCentral()` in your `build.gradle` file? Do you have JARs in your `libs` folder?

Comment: yes and i will post the build.gradle